# How can i know item of RecyclerView showing entirety

Tags: android

#### I do know how to get visible items from RecyclerView using LinearManager and count it showing in entirety.

> #### This picture the yellow item showing some part don't count it as showing.
>
> [image]
>
> #### This picture the yellow item showing entirety count it as showing.
>
> [image]

### My ideas are

- Top/Bottom position of pixel of yellow item is not in range of screen count it as not showing.
- Another items before/after yellow item is showing count it as showing.

### Any one got any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following methods

> LinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
>   LinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html

Answer (score 1):

[`findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition()), a method in the `LinearLayoutManager` class will return the adapter position of the first visible view, even if it is only partially visible.

[`findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) will return the adapter position of the first completely visible view.

use `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` and `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` for visible items towards the tail end of the list.